# convert pounds to gallons with a known specific gravity

Tags: math, formulas, chemistry

I'm working at a terminal that does liquid storage.  I need to write a calculator that can result in a pound and gallons.

For trucks, they come in on a scale to get weighed when its full, empty the liquid, then get back on the scale empty.  This scale measures in pounds.  The NET is the amount of liquid from the truck.

Two questions:

Q1) -------

If the liquid is 2-Ethylhexanol, how do I convert it to gallons knowing:

a) 45000 pounds of product (net)
b) Specific Gravity is 0.833 (20 °C)
c) weight of water 8.3378 per gallon

is the calculation 8.3378*.833 = 6.9453817 pounds per gallon? Is so, then do I just simply multiply 45000*6.9453817 to get the gallons?

Q2) --------

After I figure out the gallons.  Then I need to figure out how to do Volume Correction Factors.  For example, at 72 degrees Fahrenheit, how many gallons of volume does it take up? At 60 degrees using the example above it takes up 6.945 gallons.  I should multiple the 6.945*VCF.  What is the formula for getting the VCF?

Comment: This looks more like physics or chemistry, rather than a question about programming.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is mostly about physics/chemistry aspects of the problem.

Comment: It's 45000/(0.833*8.3378) to get gallons. I don't know about Volume Correction Factors.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics, physics, or chemistry, not programming or software development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working as a chemist in a lab, I never use pounds and gallons and would rather use the density than the specific gravity. Anyway, different places, different concepts.

You are completely out of luck looking for a **general** *volume correction factor*. There is not such thing.

The thermal volume expansion coefficients are specific to the liquid. Your only chance is find a reliable compilation of these data. The [CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics](http://www.hbcpnetbase.com/) is the first source where I'd look for these.

Comment: Thank you Klaus.  I looked to the customers to provide me a table of agreed temperature corrections.